# Create bar charts by grouped columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = [[2008, 'A', 12.2], [2008, 'A', 11.3], [2009, 'A', 4.2], [2010, 'A', 3.4], [2011, 'A', 14.2],
        [2008, 'B', 4.1], [2008, 'B', 17.2], [2009, 'B', 12.2], [2008, 'C', 12.2], [2011, 'C', 12.2]]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['year', 'type', 'income'])
```

I'd like to group the data by year and type, and plot histograms of income distribution by year for each category.

Now I can loop through the pivot table:

```
for i in df['type'].unique():
    df[df['type'] == i].pivot_table(index='year', columns = 'type', values='income', aggfunc='sum').plot(kind = 'bar')
    plt.show()
```

But it seems to me that there must be some simpler way to do this. I would be grateful for help.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
df.groupby(['type', 'year']).sum().groupby(level='type').plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

An interesting alternative:

```
(df.pivot_table(index='year', columns='type', values='income', aggfunc='sum')
   .plot.bar(subplots=True, figsize=(4,10))
)
```

Output:

[image]